# NSMutableArray just keeps the value of last loop iteration?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to index a `UITableView` which will view a friends names, so I have an `NSArray` with all friends names, from A-Z, what I have done for now is compute the number of friends for each letter like : A = 20, B = 15, and so on and put these counts in an `NSArray`.

What I need to do now is try to put every names belong to (example A letter) in array and then store this array in an `NSMutableDictionary` to be like this :

```
A =         (
        Ali,
        Alaa,
        Asdsd,
        Awer,
        asdft
    );
```

and the rest of the letter like the 'A' also.

Since I know the size of names for each letter (the sizes in `self.charcherSize` ) Here is my code that assign each name belongs to a specific letter and add them into `NSMutableArray` "names" and after done from that letter group add that group to `NSMutableDictionary` "row" and then add it to the `NSMutableArray` "content":

```
NSMutableArray *content = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *row = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

int startPoint = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [self.charcherSize count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger max = [[self.charcherSize objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] + startPoint;

    for (int j = startPoint; j < max; j++) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [self.friendsInfo objectAtIndex:j];

        [names addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    [row setValue:names forKey:charcher];
    [content addObject:row];
    startPoint = max;
}
```

but the problem is that the `NSMutableArray` "content" just hold the value of the last letter and copy these values to all dictionary's values like this :

```
(
    {
    "A" =         (
        "Zzz",
        "Zzz1",
        "Zzz2",
    );
},
    {
    "B" =         (
        "Zzz",
        "Zzz1",
        "Zzz2",
    );
},
    {
    "C" =         (
        "Zzz",
        "Zzz1",
        "Zzz2",
    );
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with characterSize and counts, I think the easier way to do this is to create a mutable dictionary, not a mutable array, since your array only contains one object anyway, a dictionary.  So here is how I would do it (assuming that friendsInfo is an array of names):

```
NSMutableDictionary *indexed = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *aName in friendsInfo){
    if (![[indexed allKeys] containsObject:[aName substringToIndex:1]]) {
        [indexed setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:aName] forKey:[aName substringToIndex:1]];
    }else{
        [[indexed valueForKey:[aName substringToIndex:1]] addObject:aName];

    }
}
    NSLog(@"%@",indexed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have picked a fairly complex way for doing this. I would look at the `NSPredicate` class (eg the `BEGINSWITH` predicate) and then use the `[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate]` method to generate the arrays with names for each letter.